# id3v2 reports "No ID3 tag" on MP3 file but VLC shows tags on same file

Tags: id3, id3v2

On my NAS I have a lot of MP3 files ripped from audio CDs I own and tagged with EasyTAG. The tags show just fine when playing the files in VLC. EasyTAG also shows them correctly when opening the files again. But when I try to extract them on the command line with `id3v2` the tool reports:

```
tilman@Neon:~$ id3v2 -l track01.mp3 
track01.mp3: No ID3 tag
```

Trying `mp3info` which is supposed to show ID3v1 tags results in:

```
tilman@Neon:~$ mp3info track01.mp3 
track01.mp3 does not have an ID3 1.x tag.
```

What could be the reason for this and, more importantly, how can I successfully extract the tags?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.